# The new tag ASIDE

Tags: html

I wonder how to use the new tag ASIDE.
Does it needs to include only text or also some sections tags inside it?

For exmaple:
If I have a whole news block in the right side of the page something like:

```
<font size="5px">News</font><br>                            
<section id="news">
    <?php require 'news.php'; ?>
</section>
```

So the aside tag will include all of that code? or it will replace the

```
<section id="news">
```

To

```
<aside id="news">
```

Comment: If you're still using `<font>` elements, I don't think you need to worry about HTML5 elements. (Hint: stop using `<font>` tags, they're long-deprecated and, now, *[obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)*.)

Comment: that's off topic but if you mentioned that, what is the alternative tag then?

Comment: Alternative to `<font>`? Use CSS. (If you follow the link in the previous comment, it'll be a start.)

Comment: For example  `<span class="smaller">Text</span>` using CSS `.smaller { font-size: 0.5em; }`

Comment: Thanks guys, and what about my question I posted above? :)

Comment: Explaning `aside` could take a moment. Rather search for an explanation on the web. This question shows not much research effort. This is getting too chatty, sorry. -- Sample explanation: http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/

Comment: Further to Smamatti's comment, this isn't a programming question (it's more of a reference question). I'd suggest reading about the [`<aside>` tag reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything *inside* of the [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-aside-element) is "content that is tangentially related to the content around the `aside` element".

So the (what seems to be a heading) "News" should be *inside* of the `aside`.

In general, `aside` can contain everything: text only, several `section`/`article` elements, `img`, `form`, …. **It depends on your content.**

For a simple list of links to news articles, you could use the following snippet:

```
<aside>
  <h1>News</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><!-- link to a news article --></li>
    <li><!-- link to a news article --></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

---

Note that you should never use `font` (it’s obsolete; use CSS), and note that you are misusing [`br`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) (you should only use it for meaningful line breaks, e.g., in addresses or poems; use CSS for "decorative" line breaks).